# CPP guidelines: Reseating a smart pointer

Tags: unique-ptr

R.33 is confusing me. Can someone care to explain further? The meaning of "reseating" doesn't seem to work here. ??

R.33: Take a unique_ptr& parameter to express that a function reseats thewidget
Reason Using unique_ptr in this way both documents and enforces the function call’s reseating semantics.

Note “reseat” means “making a pointer or a smart pointer refer to a different object.”

Example
void reseat(unique_ptr&); // "will" or "might" reseat pointer
Example, bad
void thinko(const unique_ptr&); // usually not what you want

Answer (score 0):

From the [CPP guideline](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#r35-take-a-shared_ptrwidget-parameter-to-express-that-a-function-might-reseat-the-shared-pointer):

> "reseat" means "making a reference or a smart pointer refer to a different object."

---

From [modernescpp.com](http://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-passing-smart-pointer):

> Let's look at each function signature in isolation. What does this
>   mean from the function perspective?
>
> ```
> void share(std::shared_ptr<Widget> shaWid)
> ```
>
> I'm for the lifetime of the function body a shared owner of the
>   Widget. At the begin of the function body, I will increase the
>   reference counter; at the end of the function, I will decrease the
>   reference counter; therefore, the Widget will stay alive, as long as I
>   use it.
>
> ---
>
> ```
> void reseat(std::shared_ptr<Widget>& shaWid)
> ```
>
> I'm not a shared owner of the Widget, because I will not change the
>   reference counter. I have not guaranteed that the Widget will stay
>   alive during the execution of my function, but I can reseat the
>   resource. A non-const lvalue reference is more like: I borrow the
>   resource and can reseat it.
>
> ---
>
> ```
> void mayShare(const std::shared_ptr<Widget>& shaWid)
> ```
>
> I only borrow the resource. Either can I extend the lifetime of the
>   resource nor can I reseat the resource. To be honest, you should use a
>   pointer (Widget*) or a reference (Widget&) as a parameter instead,
>   because there is no added value in using a std::shared_ptr.